# Changing scenes with Alert Boxes

Tags: class, javafx, scene

I am writing a quiz application which will feature multiple different classes including a separate class for each question. I want to use Alert Boxes to give the user the option to move onto the next question, so when I press proceed to move onto the first question, however it wont change to the next scene and I dont quite understand how the buttonType works?
Any help would be appreciated

```
package pkg1;

import java.io.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.Window;

public class Register {
    Stage stage;
    public Register (Stage b){
        stage = b;
    }

    public void start(Stage stage){
        stage.setTitle("Registration");

        GridPane gridPane = createRegisterPane();
        addUIControls(gridPane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane, 800, 500);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.show();
    }


    private GridPane createRegisterPane() {
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();

        gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(40, 40, 40, 40));

        gridPane.setHgap(10);

        gridPane.setVgap(10);


        return gridPane;
    }

    private void addUIControls(GridPane gridPane) {
        // Add Header
        Label headerLabel = new Label("Registration");
        headerLabel.setFont(Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.BOLD, 24));
        gridPane.add(headerLabel, 0,0,2,1);
        GridPane.setHalignment(headerLabel, HPos.CENTER);
        GridPane.setMargin(headerLabel, new Insets(20, 0,20,0));

        // FULL NAME
        Label fnamelabel = new Label("Full Name : ");
        gridPane.add(fnamelabel, 0,1);

        // FULL NAME TEXT
        TextField fnamefield     = new TextField();
        fnamefield.setPrefHeight(40);
        gridPane.add(fnamefield, 1,1);
        fnamefield.setPromptText(" - Enter your full name - ");

        // EMAIL
        Label emaillabel = new Label("Email: ");
        gridPane.add(emaillabel, 0, 2);

        // EMAIL TEXT
        TextField emailfield = new TextField();
        emailfield.setPrefHeight(40);
        gridPane.add(emailfield, 1, 2);
        emailfield.setPromptText(" - Enter your Email - ");

        // USERNAME
        Label usernamelabel = new Label("Username: ");
        gridPane.add(usernamelabel, 0, 3);

        // USERNAME TEXT
        TextField usernamefield = new TextField();
        usernamefield.setPrefHeight(40);
        gridPane.add(usernamefield, 1, 3);
        usernamefield.setPromptText(" - Enter your username - ");

        // PASSWORD
        Label passwordlabel = new Label("Password: ");
        gridPane.add(passwordlabel, 0, 4);

        // PASSWORD TEXT
        PasswordField passwordfield = new PasswordField();
        passwordfield.setPrefHeight(40);
        gridPane.add(passwordfield, 1, 4);
        passwordfield.setPromptText(" - Enter your password - ");

        // SUBMIT BUTTON
        Button submitButton = new Button("Submit");
        submitButton.setPrefHeight(40);
        submitButton.setDefaultButton(true);
        submitButton.setPrefWidth(100);
        gridPane.add(submitButton, 0, 5, 4, 2);
        GridPane.setHalignment(submitButton, HPos.CENTER);
        GridPane.setMargin(submitButton, new Insets(20, 0,20,0));

        submitButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                if(fnamefield.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    ErrorAlert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR,         
     gridPane.getScene().getWindow(), "Error!", "Please enter your full name.");
                    return;
                }
                if(usernamefield.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    ErrorAlert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR,      
     gridPane.getScene().getWindow(), "Error!", "Please enter your username");
                    return;
                }
                if(emailfield.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    ErrorAlert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, 
     gridPane.getScene().getWindow(), "Error!", "Please enter your Email");
                    return;
                }
                if(passwordfield.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    ErrorAlert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, 
     gridPane.getScene().getWindow(), "Error!", "Please enter your password");
                    return;
                }

        String fullname = fnamefield.getText();
        String email = emailfield.getText();
        String username = usernamefield.getText();
        String password = passwordfield.getText();

        String all = fullname + "," + email + "," + username + "," + password;
        try{
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter ("F:/NEW/1/src/pkg1/Register.txt",true);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter (fw);
            out.println(all);
            out.close();
        }   
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error " + e);
        }
        showAlert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION, gridPane.getScene().getWindow(), "Registration Succesful!", "Welcome " + fnamefield.getText());



            }
        });
    }


     //alert box which is called
    private void ErrorAlert(Alert.AlertType alertType, Window owner, String 
     title, String message){
        Alert AlertError = new Alert (AlertType.ERROR);
        AlertError.setTitle(title);
        AlertError.setHeaderText(null);
        AlertError.setContentText(message);
        AlertError.initOwner(owner);
        AlertError.show();

    }
    private void showAlert(Alert.AlertType alertType, Window owner, String title, String message) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(alertType.CONFIRMATION);
        alert.setTitle(title);
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setContentText(message);
        alert.initOwner(owner);
        alert.show();

        ButtonType b1 = new ButtonType ("Proceed");
        ButtonType b2 = new ButtonType ("Cancel");
        ButtonType b3 = new ButtonType ("Back to Main Menu");

        alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(b1,b2,b3);

        if (alert.getResult() == b1) {
            new QuestionOne(stage).start(stage);

        }else if (alert.getResult() == b2){
            new Register(stage).start(stage);

        }else {
                        new Register(stage).start(stage);
            //new Main (stage).start(stage);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the button types ***before*** showing the alert and use `Dialog.showAndWait` to "wait" for the result:

```
...
alert.initOwner(owner);

ButtonType b1 = new ButtonType("Proceed");
ButtonType b2 = new ButtonType("Cancel");
ButtonType b3 = new ButtonType("Back to Main Menu");

alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(b1,b2,b3);

Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
ButtonType resButton = result.orElse(null);

if (resButton == b1) {
    ...
} else if (resButton == b2) {
    ...
} else if (resButton == b3) {
    ...
}
```

---

Also as mentioned previously: A `Application` class without a constructor that takes no parameters cannot be launched. Your `main` method won't work.

Comment: Hm, I just get alot of errors, may I ask what the line with resButton does?

Comment: It gets the value from the `Optional`, if it's assigned and uses the parameter passed to the method otherwise...